# PHP: Serve a file for download without providing the direct link

Tags: php

I want to serve invoices for download. Currently I'm using a simple numbering scheme (invoice-01.pdf, invoice-02.pdf, and so on). I know that I could use hashes instead to obscure the data.

Is it also possible to use PHP and serve the invoices by not directly having the user point to them?

Comment: Yes. How about "http://invoices.invalid/request.php?id=baeba7e7b9ec453e23b5bac313219285d6292358" ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is even an example of this on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

Or expand that a bit with

```
<?php
if ( can_this_file_be_downloaded() ) {
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"');
  readfile("{$_GET['filename']}.pdf");
} else {
  die("None shall pass");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Sam has the answer. Also put them in a directory with .htaccess:

```
Authname Private
AuthType basic
require user noadmittance
```

That will keep out direct access if they know the url. You can still read it from your PHP script with readfile().

Comment: Because of your suggestion I just had another idea: I put all the invoices outside of the www folder. :-) Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah even better!

Answer (score 4):

I found for this excellent guide: [How to serve big files through PHP](http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/).

Especially useful is the lighttpd trick - If your PHP happens to run under lighhtpd, script only needs to set "X-Sendfile" header, and lighttpd will read and send the file for you (and it well knows how to send files).

**UPDATE:**

> Lighttpd has this feature and there is a mod_xsendfile for Apache2.

(Quoted from [NginX documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile))

Answer (score 1):

My function with automatic MIME type detection :

```
function serve_file($filepath, $new_filename=null) {
    $filename = basename($filepath);
    if (!$new_filename) {
        $new_filename = $filename;
    }
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($filepath);
    header('Content-type: '.$mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_filename.'"');
    readfile($filepath);
}
```

usage :

```
serve_file("/no_apache/invoice27342.pdf");
```

Pay attention to not send anything else with PHP (no echo).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should clean the output buffer before streaming the file, otherwise it may not open. If you're downloading an EXE, the code signing certificate may be corrupted. This may not matter on EXEs that are not code signed, but this is the cleanest method to ensure code signing still is intact by delivering only the file and no 'extra' headers/output.

This is close to another answer, but `ob_clean();` has been inserted before the headers.

```php
function serve_file($filepath, $new_filename = null) {
    $filename = basename($filepath);
    if (!$new_filename) {
        $new_filename = $filename;
    }
    $mime_type = mime_content_type($filepath);
    ob_clean();
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
    readfile($filepath);
}
```

Usage:

```php
serve_file($url, $filename);
```

Example:

```php
$url = "example.exe";
$filename = "Example123.exe";
serve_file($url, $filename);
```